# Merging several csv files (more than 200) into one csv file in python

Tags: python, dataframe, merge

i have more than 200  data frames with different file names that share 2 columns: "estado" and "ciclo", each dataframe have only one more column that i want to link with the common columns.

I have this code in order to download the files into my directory:

```
extension = 'csv'
all_filenames = [i for i in glob.glob('*.{}'.format(extension))]
```

however, i want to read all the files in all_filenames and then merging into one dataframe.

Comment: Surely you have more than just this? (It's a good start. Don't give up yet.)

Comment: Right, keep going.  Your question could be expanded too.  Your title says you want to "merge" the files . . . not just "concatenate" then all together which would be easy.  What are you merging on?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you could Google for a solution much faster than it would take to craft together the words to create your question here.

```
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd
os.chdir("C:\\schemas\\")


extension = 'csv'
all_filenames = [i for i in glob.glob('*.{}'.format(extension))]


#combine all files in the list
combined_csv = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f) for f in all_filenames ])
#export to csv
combined_csv.to_csv( "C:\\combined_csv.csv", index=False, encoding='utf-8-sig')
```